# How to use non native cordova plugins in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic2

I am trying to use this cordova plugin https://github.com/honza889/cordova-plugin-kiosk in an Ionic v2 App.

Basically after installing the plugin in cordova with `cordova plugin add https://github.com/honza889/cordova-plugin-kiosk.git` the plugin is enabled and working.

But I can't find a way to use the plugin's methods.

`window.plugins` is undefined

and `cordova` is undefined.

I have tried to import the plugin in app.component.ts but I can't figure out the right path.

Does anyone know a way to use non native plugins in an Ionic V2 app (the documentation and resources are outdated or referring to native plugins).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Andreas Gassmann's answer work very well. For those who wonder how to access `window.plugins.{plugin-name}.{property-or-method}`, despite compilation errors : you can use `window['plugins']...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to simply access the `KioskPlugin` variable in your code. The typescript compiler will not know that variable, so you have to declare it first:

```
declare let KioskPlugin: any;

@Component({
  ...
})
export class TestPage {

  ...

  exitKiosk() {
    KioskPlugin.exitKiosk();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was missing. I am not that familiar with typescript. I played with the plug-in in the `chrome://inspect console`  and it didn't fit my needs. I am ending up writing it myself, so your insight is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: i have tried it the way specified above but still its not working can some one help me out. following is the issue: file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js: Line 3 : Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./MyApp class MyApp - inline template:0:0 caused by: KioskPlugin is not defined
ReferenceError: KioskPlugin is not defined

Comment: Did you add `declare let KioskPlugin: any;` to the beginning of the MyApp class file?

Comment: i have done that still no change, why ionic 2 we is causing problems in integrating cordova plugins (non ionic native plugins) i am also working on other plugin integration https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase even this is also not working.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am investigating the same problem.

Comment: I am still at the same problem as well with the Uncaught(in promise) error message.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue trying to access to a custom plugin and I finally solved thanks to this post:
 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/525

Adding `declare var cordova: any;` instead of my custom plugin var, and calling through `cordova.plugins.myCustomPlugin.myFunction()` did the trick.

Indeed, depends on the settings in the plugin.xml file of the plugin you want to use. More concretely on the `<clobbers target="variable.MyCustomPlugin" />` tag, which determines where the plugin js files will be exported. Another posibility for example would be `declare var window: any;` and then `window.myCustomPlugin.myFunction()`

Hope it helps ;)